# RxJava: Return List Containing Past And Current Result

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable, rx-android

I want to chain a continous data stream and create a list of result containing the past results. I can do it with the following code. Is there a way NOT to have a variable outside the rx-chain? Thank you!

```
- [0]
- [0, 1]
- [0, 1, 2]
- [0, 1, 2, 3]
- [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
- [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

```java
final List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

Observable
        .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Long number) {
                list.add(number);
                System.out.println("- " + list);
            }
        });

Thread.sleep(100000000L);
```

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

```java
Observable
        .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addToPastResultList()      // <--- something like this?
        .subscribe(new Action1<List<Long>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<Long> list) {
                System.out.println("- " + list);
            }
        });

Thread.sleep(100000000L);
```

Comment: You need a list somewhere to store the values, maybe you can put the Observable into a method and use a local variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `scan` operator

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .scan(new ArrayList<>(), (list, integer) -> {
            list.add(integer);
            return list;
        })
        .subscribe(list -> System.out.println(list));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my question... looks like i can create a map with a private variable to deal with it.

```java
Observable
        .interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map(new Func1<Long, List<Long>>() {
            private List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
            @Override
            public List<Long> call(Long number) {
                list.add(number);
                return list;
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Action1<List<Long>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<Long> list) {
                System.out.println("- " + list);
            }
        });

Thread.sleep(100000000L);
```

Comment: Doesn't that always just make a list of one number?

Comment: looks like the map function instance will be stored in the chain, it will be reused in each iteration. from my tests it produced the result i wanted.

Comment: Sidenote: if you do `.toBlocking().subscribe`, you don't need the Thread.sleep